# The insert method in the service "mysteries" inserts everything but not which I ask it to

Tags: c#, silverlight, insert

I cannot understand the mistake.

### error

None, but no records get inserted. nothing happens.

### mysteries

The insert method in the service  "mysteries" inserts everything but not which I ask it to.

For the customerid value it keeps on inserting numbers 30118 - 30119 and so on in every insert, irrespective of what I ask it to insert

### xaml.cs

```
 /// </summary>
        public About()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Title = ApplicationStrings.AboutPageTitle;


            ServiceReference1.Customer new_customer = new ServiceReference1.Customer();
            //feeding data to the instance
            new_customer.CustomerID = 9999999;
            new_customer.NameStyle = false;
            new_customer.FirstName = "first_name";
            new_customer.LastName = "last_name";
            new_customer.PasswordHash = "password_hash";
            new_customer.PasswordSalt = "pass_salt";
            new_customer.rowguid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            new_customer.ModifiedDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date;

            ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

            client.DoInsertCompleted += new System.EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_DoInsertCompleted);

            client.DoInsertAsync(new_customer);
        }

        void client_DoInsertCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            label1.Content = "Inserted";
        }
```

### svc.cs

```
namespace BusinessApplication2.Web
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public List<Customer> DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here

            BusinessApplication2.Web.AdventureWorksLTEntities alpha = new AdventureWorksLTEntities();

            var selected_rows = from rows in alpha.Customers select rows;

            return selected_rows.ToList();
        }



        [OperationContract]
        public void DoInsert(Customer alpha)
        {

            //create db object
            BusinessApplication2.Web.AdventureWorksLTEntities db = new AdventureWorksLTEntities();
            //create a new table object
            Customer new_customer = new Customer();

            new_customer.CustomerID = alpha.CustomerID;
            new_customer.NameStyle = alpha.NameStyle;
            new_customer.FirstName = alpha.FirstName;
            new_customer.LastName = alpha.LastName;
            new_customer.PasswordHash = alpha.PasswordHash;
            new_customer.PasswordSalt = alpha.PasswordSalt;
            new_customer.rowguid = alpha.rowguid;
            new_customer.ModifiedDate = alpha.ModifiedDate;

            db.Customers.AddObject(new_customer);
            db.AcceptAllChanges();
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Dispose();

            return;


        }//insert to customer ends
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that you do not have IdentityInsert turned off?

Comment: ? plz provide how to turn it off or on.. so that i can tell if i did something as you saying

Comment: In your database go to you CustomerId column and change the IdentityInsert to on.  This will allow you to insert Ids into your column.  If it is tunred off, the database engine will do this for you.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT  *Table* ON

I don't recommend doing this though...  Unless you really need it.  Do not forget to update your datamodel afterwards.